# Scientificalicious

Tags: discussion, tags

Right now, we have [scientific-computing](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scientific-computing), [scientific](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scientific), and [science](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science) tags.

The "-computing" is redundant given the nature of this site.  How about we pick either "scientific" or "science" and move everything in the other two tags into that one?

Comment: Good points! `scientific` is just gone (was only 1 Q, and even that was "on hold"). Wondering about the distribution: Again, only 1 Q for `science`, but 14 in `scientific-computing`. Looks like most "questioners" feel `science` too generic. And I can imagine a difference between the terms like `scientific-computing` as processing of data to find out their relation – and `science` being other rather "supporting" stuff (like periodic tables or other lookups, or science-specifc archival/document processing). Not exactly my area of expertice.

Comment: @Izzy Yes.  Tags are an interesting phenomena.  Part of me says "Use whatever people choose naturally" and part of me recognizes that once a tag exists, however imperfect, it biases other people to use it.  I think the bottom line is to have what helps people find what they want... and I think that takes some real thought to determine how to best facilitate that functionality.

Answer (score 6):

[Scientific computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_science) is a *subset* of software used for sciences. For example [iOS: Chemical/Molecule Viewer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14303/ios-chemical-molecule-viewer) is about science but not about scientific computing. [Real Time (<10ms response) Graphing/Charting](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18103/real-time-10ms-response-graphing-charting) isn't particularly about science.

I think we can drop [science](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science) (which I'm guilty of having created) and stick with tags for individual sciences such as [chemistry](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemistry), with [scientific-computing](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scientific-computing) used when appropriate (I haven't reviewed whether the current uses are appropriate).

Answer (score -4):

I think we should synonym [scientific-computing](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scientific-computing) to [science](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science), thus making [science](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science) the main tag. We don't serve non-computing stuff here, but it seems that people think its necessary to explicitly say that they need computing to be done.

So, the better tag is [science](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science), but as people have used [scientific-computing](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scientific-computing) to express what they mean we should keep it as synonym.

Comment: [Scientific computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_science) is a subset of software used for sciences. For example http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14303/ios-chemical-molecule-viewer is about science but not about scientific computing. I suspect we shouldn't have [tag:science] at all, it's too broad — but on the other hand it only exists on one question (and there was another one with [tag:scientific]).

Comment: @Gilles "there was another one with scientific": I re-tagged that one (see my comment on the question here itself). I fully agree with you that 'science' is much too broad (which is why I did what I did). I also agree the better way would be tags like `chemistry` (+1 on your answer from me). I just think we should split that off later, when enough questions exist – tags with only 1 question don't survive very long :)